# Can the Angular $injector be decorated with $provide.decorator?

Tags: angularjs

*Perhaps this is a terrible idea, but if it is then please tell me why and then pretend that it's an academic exercise that won't see the light of day in production.*

I'd like to add some logic to the Angular $injector service, to monitor when certain services are injected into other services. Since it seems that Angular provides a mechanism for decorating services, I thought this would be the way to go. However, the following code throws an error.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$injector', ['$log', '$delegate', addLoggingToInjector]);
    }]);

    function addLoggingToInjector($log, $delegate) {
        var baseInstantiate = $delegate.instantiate;
        var baseInvoke = $delegate.invoke;

        $delegate.instantiate = function (type, locals) {
            // $log.debug('Calling $injector.instantiate');

            baseInstantiate(type, locals);
        };

        $delegate.invoke = function (fn, self, locals) {
            // $log.debug('Calling $injector.invoke');

            baseInvoke(fn, self, locals);
        };

        return $delegate;
    };
})();
```

The specific error is:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $injectorProvider

Comment: Did you find a way to detect which service you were injecting into?

Comment: Yes. I added a run function to the ng module that accepts the $injector as a parameter and overrides the methods on the service. I basically followed the pattern proposed by @KayakDave below.

Comment: Can you detect, for example, that you are injecting `$log` into `MyCtrl`?  Or just that you are injecting `$log`?

Comment: Only that I'm injecting $log. However, if you override the register function of the $controllerProvider, you can record the name of the controller on the injectable. Then when the injector receives it, you can extract the name and know what you are injecting into. For this to work though, you need to override the register method before declaring any of your controllers, since this all happens at config time.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Was thinking of automagically adding controller information to the logging service.

Comment: Yeah that was my use case as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use the Angular decorator service on $injector.  As Artur notes `$injector` is a bit different from other services.  But we can create our own decorator.

### Why we can't use Angular's decorator

At the code level the issue is that `$injector` doesn't have a constructor function- there's no `$injectorProvider`.

For example both of these return true:

```
$injector.has('$location');
$injector.has('$locationProvider')
```

However, while this returns true:

```
$injector.has('$injector')
```

this returns false:

```
$injector.has('$injectorProvider')
```

We see the importance when we look at the [Angular decorator](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a0ed3713899f0ec5f3e1b76ef48fc3acedabe1a5/src/auto/injector.js) function:

```
function decorator(serviceName, decorFn) {
   var origProvider = providerInjector.get(serviceName + providerSuffix),
       orig$get = origProvider.$get;

   origProvider.$get = function() {
      var origInstance = instanceInjector.invoke(orig$get, origProvider);
     return instanceInjector.invoke(decorFn, null, {$delegate: origInstance});
   };
}
```

And

```
providerSuffix = 'Provider'
```

So the Angular decorator expects to operate on the service's constructor (`serviceName + providerSuffix`).  Pragmatically, **since we don't have an `$injectorProvider` we can't use decorator**.

### Solution

What we can do is override the Angular injector's [`get` function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector) ourselves by replacing the injector's default `get` with one that calls the original, Angular defined, `get` followed by our function.

We'll apply this to `$injector` rather than the nonexistent `$injectorProvider` like so:

```
app.config(['$provide','$injector', function ($provide,$injector) {

    // The function we'll add to the injector
    myFunc = function () {
        console.log("injector called ", arguments);
    };

    // Get a copy of the injector's get function
    var origProvider = $injector,
        origGet = origProvider.get;

    //Override injector's get with our own
    origProvider.get = function() {

        // Call the original get function 
        var returnValue = origGet.apply(this, arguments);

        // Call our function
        myFunc.apply(this,arguments);

        return returnValue;
    }
}]);
```

You'll see the provider being injected is the first augment, so `app.value('aValue', 'something');` yields the following log statement:

```
injector called  ["aValueProvider"]
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cZnK/3/)

Comment: Few comments: `$injector.get('$injector')` always equals `$injector`. Angular `decorator` overrides the `$get` of the provider -- the function that is used to create the concrete instance of the service. It is mere coincidence that `$injector` has a function called `get`, so I do not think that it is the best analogy to compare `$get` from providers world with `a_function` from instance world. (or please explain bit further what you meant by this?). Anyway, thanks a lot for inspiration. +1

Comment: @artur Good point about $injector- I took that from the decorator code so I'd parallel it.  But you're definitely right that could be cleaned up.  I don't think `get` is a coincidence. Although I think you're right that `$get` is the constructor version of `get` and there are implications to that.  But I don't think they bite us here.  It appears to me that Angular uses $injector like a service (including using `get` on it) but since it manually instantiates it there's no need for a constructor like there is for every other service. But I'm just guessing based on what I see in the code.

Comment: 100%: `$get` is generic name for every provider for a method with which instance of a service/filter/etc is created (it lives in provider world) *vs.* `get` in `$injector` is a method by which a service is returned (it lives in concrete instance world). Maybe you are right, that the names are somehow connected :-) *I took that from the decorator code so I'd parallel it* there is a slight difference in `decorator function`: first they `get` concrete provider and than they decorate its `$get` method :-)

Comment: After a bit of poking in the code I'm not seeing anything that feel definitive on whether the naming of `get` and `$get` were coincidence.  It feels like there's a connection to me- but I can't point to a line that shows it.  It's been a good exploration in any case- thanks for the push.  I'll update `origProvider` in the code, per your comment.  We still need two variables so we have pointers to the new and old- but it's cleaner now.  Thanks!  +1

Comment: it may be even cleaner: `var origGet = $injector.get; $injector.get = function() { myFunc.apply(this,arguments); return origGet.apply(this, arguments); }`

Comment: Good point.  I like having the two variables personally- it feels like it documents what's happening a hair more (by drawing out the connection between the two).  But clearly yours is cleaner- and a hair faster

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @KayakDave Might also want to extend/override the `has` method if your function call is intercepting any modules

Answer (score 13):

The answer is: no.

---

`$provide.decorator` is used to **intercept service creation** -- that is why it is called from `.config` block, when there is still time to configure all services, as none of them has been created. `$provide.decorator` basically gets the `Provider` of the service and swaps its `$get` with newly delivered `decorFn`.

`$injector` is not like other services. It is created, as **the very first** step of `bootstrapping` an application -- way before `app.config` is called. [look at functions: `bootstrap` and `createInjector` in angular source code]

But hey, you can achieve your goal quite easily by tweaking the source code just a bit :-) Particularly look at `function invoke(fn, self, locals)`.

---

**UPDATE** I got some inspiration from @KayakDave. You actually do not have to dig in the source-code itself. You can use the following pattern to observe each call to any of `$injector` methods:

```
 app.config(['$injector', function ($injector) {

      $injector.proper =
      {
          get : $injector.get,
          invoke : $injector.invoke,
          instantiate : $injector.instantiate,
          annotate : $injector.annotate,
          has : $injector.has
      }

      function getDecorator(serviceName)
      {
          console.log("injector GET: ", serviceName);
          return this.proper.get(serviceName);
      }

      function invokeDecorator(fn, self, locals)
      {
          console.log("injector INVOKE: ", fn, self, locals);
          return this.proper.invoke(fn, self, locals);
      }

      function instantiateDecorator(Type, locals)
      {
          console.log("injector INSTANTIATE: ", Type, locals);
          return this.proper.instantiate(Type, locals);
      }

      function annotateDecorator (fn)
      {
          console.log("injector ANNOTATE: ", fn);
          return this.proper.annotate(fn);
      }

      function hasDecorator(name)
      {
          console.log("injector HAS: ", name);
          return this.proper.has(name);
      }

      $injector.get = getDecorator;
      $injector.invoke = invokeDecorator;
      $injector.instantiate = instantiateDecorator;
      $injector.annotate = annotateDecorator;
      $injector.has = hasDecorator;
  }]);
```

---

<kbd>[PLNKR](http://jsfiddle.net/9cZnK/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Your update is very cool and I appreciate its completeness. Thanks so much!