# Is it possible to unit test an Angular app without using injected/provide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When unit testing a controller or service in Angular, it seems conventional to `provide` the mocked dependencies, and allow Angular's DI system wire-up the object under test.

Is this correct?

I only ask since in my own personal experience, using a DI framework within your unit tests is generally a bad practice, where the recommended alternative is to manually compose the object under test. Of course, this may just be how Angular is intended to be used, but it differs from my experience of conventional unit testing, so thought I'd ask!

Comment: I don't use provide for my unit tests. I just Manually compose the object.

Comment: Do you do this for services / objects provided from Angular's `factory` method? If so, how? :)

Comment: I also do not use provide to test, but you have to ensure that you're not creating your units (controllers/services/factories) in-line, this way you have access to instantiate them from your unit test.

Comment: To clarify: the implementation in your controllers etc. don't have any real logic beyond constructing an object and running some `init` method on it? Would it be possible to see an example?

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield Yeah, actually I do do what you are saying now. There is no other way of doing it unless you add to global scope which has it's own set of problems. I don't really see it as bad practice as long as you are providing mocked out dependancies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Angular $injector be decorated with $provide.decorator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551277/can-the-angular-injector-be-decorated-with-provide-decorator)